# How to go to Homepage by clearing path in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to go to the homepage from A contact us page.
subscribe Views.py:(subscribe is basically contact)

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from bsdk.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER
from . import forms
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
# Create your views here.
#DataFlair #Send Email
def subscribe(request):
    sub = forms.Subscribe()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sub = forms.Subscribe(request.POST)
        name=str(sub['name'].value())
        subject = str(sub['name'].value())
        message = str(sub['phone'].value())+ "\n" + str(sub['message'].value())
        recepient = str(sub['Email'].value())
        send_mail(subject, 
            message, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recepient], fail_silently = False)
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form':sub})
```

subscribe urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from ecom import views as ecom_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('subscribe', views.subscribe, name = 'subscribe'),
]
```

**How to redirect to homepage when home is pressed on site?**
even though i tried a couple of times i ended up going to homepage but with extra path http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscribe/home when actually i wanted to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how you have configured your `urls.py` settings.
In the issue of your case, this is what must be happening: you are on the subscribe page at the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscribe` and when you click the homepage button it directs with the suffix `/home` to your `urls.py`, which may look like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('subscribe.urls'))
]
```

So you can see that the dispatch will select the second path and then will reroute to your first configuration in the `subscribe urls.py`, which gives the path `http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscribe/home`. To solve it add another path for `/home` in the main `urls.y` that is sent to a given view to display just the homepage.

Also, read on the documentation from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/)